# Remove duplicates based on values in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Person_Id = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
                             567L, 567L, 567L, 888L, 888L), 
               Result = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                          "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes")), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

As you can see, the `Result` values for `Person_id` **123** and **567** are consistent throughout the entire dataframe. However, the `Result` values for person **888** differs.
I want to filter this dataset:

1. If the result differs for a given `Person_id`, I would like them to be removed.
2. Keep only one row for a given `Person_id` IF the `Result` is consistent throughout the dataframe.

The output dataframe should look like:

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(Person_Id = c(123L, 567L), 
               Result = c("Yes", "No")), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Try `df1 %>% distinct() %>% filter(n_distinct(Result) == 1, .by = "Person_Id")` or `df1 %>% distinct() %>% group_by(Person_Id) %>% filter(n_distinct(Result) == 1)`

Comment: @akrun what's your `dplyr` version? I don't have `.by` in `filter`.

Comment: @M-- Its "experimental" since 1.1.0, 28 Jan

Comment: @M-- Sorry, i should have mentioned the `devel` version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **base R** approach using `aggregate`

```
na.omit(aggregate(Result ~ Person_Id, df1, function(x) 
  ifelse(length(unique(x)) == 1, unique(x), NA)))
  Person_Id Result
1       123    Yes
2       567     No
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Person_Id) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(Result) == 1) %>% 
  unique %>% ungroup

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Person_Id Result
#>       <int> <chr> 
#> 1       123 Yes   
#> 2       567 No
```